# How to modify a nested json position with a trace string

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a web app in order to do a json builder. The problem is I have the json in javascript and I have a string with the position of the element to change.

For me it's easy to access to it doing for loops, but the goal is update or delete the field or array.

The only success solution I have found, it's an switch with the possibles splited trace array lengths.

Json example:

```
{
    "name" : "Marcelino"
    "id" : "${id}"
    "poderes":
    {
        "poder1" : "volar"
        "poder2" : "echar fuego"
        "poder3" : "${poder4}"
        "array":
        {
             "Elemento1" : "adada"
        }
    } 
}
```

I want to modify the following key:value pair:

```
"poderes" : "volar"
```

I have the trace in a variable:

```
trace = poderes-poder1
```

The current solution

```
...
let traceArray = trace.split("-");
...
switch(traceArray.length){
...
case1:
    json[traceArray[0]]
...
case2:
    json[traceArray[0]][traceArray[1]]
...
case3:
    json[traceArray[0]][traceArray[1]][traceArray[2]]
...
```

Looking for better solution.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Also, thanks for your first question here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the path by saving the last key and change either the value or delete this property.

```js
function change(object, path, value) {
    var keys = path.split('-'),
        last = keys.pop(),
        reference = keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object);
        
    if (value === DELETE) {
        delete reference[last];
    } else {
        reference[last] = value;
    }
}

const DELETE = Symbol('delete this property');

var data = { name: "Marcelino", id: "${id}", poderes: { poder1: "volar", poder2: "echar fuego", poder3: "${poder4}", array: { Elemento1: "adada" } } },
    target = 'poderes-poder1';
    
change(data, target, 'foo')
console.log(data);

change(data, target, DELETE);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way you could tackle this is by reading the JSON into a Javascript object, mutate it and then convert it back to JSON:

```
const hero = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);

hero.poderes.poder1 = "invisibility";

const outputJson = JSON.strigify(hero);
```

Comment: First to all, thanks for the response. But with that solution I have the same problem. I don't know if I have 2 or 10 anidations, and I cant do something like hero."poderes.poder1"